# Delete order number in django

Tags: python, django, view

I have a list of order numbers. From my service order view, I can manually type in a field number to lookup for a order number to delete. This works well.

```
order = models.Order.objects.get(pk=1219)
if request.POST.get('delete'):
    order.delete()
```

Now my question. I have an edit order form with a url of `/orders/edit/(?P<order_no>\d+)/`, and in this edit order form I can go to a new page called `/quote/service_order/(?P<client_id>\d+)/(?P<request_type>\d+)/`. In the service order view, this is where an order is deleted. Instead of manually writing down the primary key value (order no), I want to delete the order number that was whatever (?P\d+) was in the edit order form url was before. Is it possible to work a solution to this? I hope I made everything clear.

Comment: "In the service order view, this is where an order is deleted"  Since the order isn't referenced in this URI, this is not a very good design.  Why isn't the Order Number part of this URI?

Comment: @S.Lott This was because this software I am working on was made like this way before. But now our client who we provide our software to that person wants to make changes. Because I have to make changes to parameters and urls, I am now even wondering if I should not make any changes.

Comment: Deleting and order from a URL that starts with `/quote` and doesn't even mention the order is a sign of a bad URL design.  You should consider fixing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept multiple parameters from query string, like this:

```
/quote/service_order/(\d+)/(\d+)
```

Then in your view:

```
# client_id - first parameter in braces from the url
# order_id - 2nd parameter in braces from the url
def order_view(request, client_id, order_id):
    order = models.Order.objects.get(pk=int(order_id))
    if request.POST.get('delete'):
        order.delete()
```

Don't forget to check if user has the permission to delete the order.